# React/Redux: How to only allow users to get to the next page based on completing a previous page?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have two pages on my webpage. I want the submit button to be disabled until the user completes the first page.

The button is disabled; however, if I try to access the second page using a link the button is enabled and I can access the second page.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the user to be unable to access the second page without finishing some task on the first page, you can

- Set a key in your redux state that you set only when the user has completed the task and then only render the second page once the key is set. That is, something like

```
{this.props.taskCompleted === true && <SecondPage />}
```

- If you're using react-router, you can create a sort of protected route like

```
const PrivateRoute = (props: any) => {
  const { component: Component, auth, ...rest } = props;
  const renderComponent = (props: any) => {
    if (auth.isTaskCompleted) {
      return <Component {...props} />;
    } else {
      return <Redirect to={'auth'} />;
    }
  };
  return <Route {...rest} render={renderComponent} />;
};

const mapStateToProps = (state: any) => ({
  auth: state.auth,
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  null,
  null,
  { pure: false },
)(PrivateRoute);
```

and then used like

```
<PrivateRoute path="/second" component={SecondPage} />
```

---

However keep in mind that none of these methods will keep someone determined, since a purely frontend authentication is never secure. You should set it up so that the data for the second page is only sent from the backend server is only sent if a particular key is set in the backend.

Comment: Hi I appreciate your answer!! Can you please help me understand this further?

Comment: @Ishawa sure, what part did you not understand?

Answer (score 0):

you can disable button using react state.

```
export class Form extends React.Component {
  state = {
    disableSubmit: true,
  }
  render() {
    return (<button disabled={this.state.disableSubmit}>Submit</button>);
  }
}
```

To disable link you can apply class. check here. https://css-tricks.com/how-to-disable-links/

```
export class Form extends React.Component {
  state = {
    disableSubmit: true,
  }
  render() {
    return (<a className={this.state.disableSubmit && "disabledLinkClass"}>Link</a>);
  }
}
```